# react native expo , GraphQl request failed error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

When I build this app in expo. I am facing this error. please help to solve this issue. I followed all instruction that required in documentation.

```
Loaded "env" configuration for the "preview" profile: no 
environment variables specified. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/
```

You don't have the required permissions to perform this operation.

```
Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[35770a4d-c717-47ce-9d63-671c3816835b] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[85db74cd-7b33-4876-9c45-7ef5c68afc4f], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1)

Request ID: 8874acd6-8e2a-47b3-994b-24d82419050a

Error: GraphQL request failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building your app with expo using a command that looks like `eas build --profile preview`

For your build to find you environment variables you must write them into the eas.json file inside the profile used on the build like the following

```
...
"build" : {
   "preview": {
     "env": {
       "NODE_ENV": "production",
       // All your env variables here
     }
   },
   "production": {
      "env": {
       ....
      }
    }
  }
...
```